# DIV Style and DIV Position not getting along

Tags: javascript, html, stylesheet

```
<div id=mmactivate style='display: none'>
<form>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="date1xx" VALUE="" SIZE=25>
<IMG SRC=CalandarIcon.png HREF="#" onClick="cal1xx.select(document.forms[0].date1xx,'anchor1xx','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" TITLE="cal1xx.select(document.forms[0].date1xx,'anchor1xx','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor1xx" ID="anchor1xx">
<DIV ID="testdiv1" STYLE="position:absolute;background-color:white;layer-background-color:white;"></DIV>
</form>
</div>
```

This code is used to activate a popup java calandar. For some reason the style='display: none' and the position:absolute; arn't playing along. If I delete one or the other it works, otherwise it does nothing when I click it...

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: The position is absolute, but you're not positioning the element, with Top, Left, etc... Maybe you should change that first...

Comment: What do you mean exactly by they're not getting along? You took them both to a party one night and the argued constantly?

Comment: And what are you trying to do? Since everything is invisible anyway, what does it matter where the div is positioned?

Comment: Sorry!!!.. I can't help you. There is no proper code here. I think @Starx is correct.

Comment: If you enclose this in the appropriate script tags, it _will_ be javascript.

Answer (score 3):

So many mistakes

1. Java is not JavaScript. <sup>*[MetalFrog]*</sup>
2. Line 1: `id=mmactivate` should be `id="mmactivate"`
3. Line 2: The form consists of no method, actions or enctype. <sup>*[Mr. Lister]*</sup>
4. Line 4: Why is there script in the `title` field?
5. Line 4: Why does an image have a `href` attribute. <sup>*[Mr. Lister]*</sup>
6. Line 4: Inline event handlers are a bad choice to start with.
7. Line 5: `testdiv1` is a child of "mmactivate", so it has to follow its parent's `display: none;`

Comment: @MetalFrog, that should be no 1

Comment: The DIV mmactivate is hidden until the user clicks a button to display it, so that is hidden when the page is loaded. When you click the button to display it, then you cannot activate the calandar

Comment: @user1186164, Where is the button to click to display the div?

Comment: And what's the HREF doing in the IMG? And uppercase tags are so last century! And it won't validate without an alt in the img.

Comment: @MrLister, My god, we could write a blog post about the errors. LOL

Comment: The button is a little lower in the form, I didnt include it in the excerpt

Comment: @user1186164 Did you try Mario's suggestion?

Comment: When I try setting the position to top, it will move everthing on the page down to make room for the calandar, instead of going over top of it

Comment: @user1186164 Can you do a jsFiddle of what you have now? `position:absolute` is not supposed to have an effect on other elements on the page, so there must be something else wrong.

Comment: Position:absolute does not have an effect on the other elements on the page. If I change it to Position:Top, then it will display when I click the button, but will move everything else on the page down.

Comment: @user1186164, And fix the issues, mentioned on this solution too.

Comment: @user1186164, extending discussion will not get you answers, show us the issue. Most favourable would be [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: `position:top` is incorrect. Change it back to `position:absolute` and add `top:0`.

Comment: Nevermind - Thanks everyone for your help. Ill try to figure it out on my own.

Comment: @user1186164 We *are* trying to help you, even though it seems that we're just nitpicking your code apart. No need to be defensive about it. We all start somewhere.

Comment: @user1186164, Just show us the issue, We will understand better. We are all here to help.

Comment: If you want to talk about attribute quotes you should also mention that all the attributes need to be in lower case. These two are only requirements in XHTML, but not in HTML. Anyway, please consider continuing in chat to avoid ending up with an unwieldy comment thread here.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn The thread has ended. The OP won't be back.